# Markov Chains : Can anything be said about what happens in between two transition?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-process, markov-chain

In time homogeneous discrete Markov chains we take a set period for a single transition. In examples we see sometimes depending on the examples the transition period being a a month a week etc. I'm wondering whether anything can be said on what happens during a transition (for example if a transition period is one month what happens after 2 weeks?) or if it is possible to reduce the transition period of the existing model which may in some cases help to improve the predictions. I do not know whether this is a valid question to ask regarding MCs, however I believe it is an interesting question that I should share here. I welcome any answers. Thanks.

Comment: Answered [there](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/914869/).

Answer (score 1):

If you collected data every month you can guess what happens after two weeks by interpolating, but that is necessarily only a guess. If you really want to know what happens every two weeks you need to collect data every two weeks.